# How to add label to Checkbox in Windows::UI::XAML::Controls

Tags: windows, winrt-xaml, devexpress-windows-ui

I am new to WINDOWS UI. Trying my hands with XAML based programming through C++.

Here is the dummy piece of code that I am trying.

```
Stackpanel st;
CheckBox checkBox;
checkBox.Name() = L"";
st().Children().Append(checkBox);
```

How can we add label to check box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using C++/WinRT and you are trying to set the content of the CheckBox control. Please try the following code:

```
  CheckBox checkBox;
    checkBox.Name(L"");
    checkBox.Content(winrt::box_value(L"Check Tag"));
    st().Children().Append(checkBox);
```

`Check Tag` should be the content that you want to add.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, Thanks a lot.. this is what I was trying to achieve..

Comment: @Tausif If my solution solves the issue, you could accept it as answer so other people who are facing the same issue will know it.

Comment: yes sir, done :)